# Windows 8 Contacts

Tags: windows-8

In Windows 8 `ContactPicker.PickMultipleContactsAsync`  the `ContactInformation.CustomFields` and `ContactInformation.InstantMessages` count is zero despite the contacts having all the details filled in.

Answer (score 1):

Try to run app from CodeSamples and check if you get values correctly:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Contact-Picker-App-sample-fc6677a1